# How to programmatically map integers to const strings?

Tags: c, error-handling, enums, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a bunch of error codes (0,1,10,11,20,30,40,...) that I need to map to their corresponding error messages. Since the error codes cannot conveniently be used as indeces into an array (it would be sparse and wasteful), I am thinking that this could somehow be accomplished with macros and/or enums.

I am basically trying to create a function `const char *my_strerror(int errorcode)`.

```
const char *err00 = "an error message";
const char *err01 = "a different one";
const char *err10 = "another one";

const char* chatter_strerror(int error){
    switch(error){
        case 0:
            return err00;
        case 1:
            return err01;
        case 10:
            return err10;

        .... // 10 more cases
    }
}
```

Surely there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You can trust your compiler to lower the switch case as efficiently as possible. So yes, this is your best bet.

Comment: You cannot do it with macros, since macros are evaluated during compile time. I am sure your error codes are generated during runtime.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Any one error code corresponds to only one error message, and that is static at compile time. And I'm not concerned with the efficiencies of the approaches, I'm more concerned with the elegance, simplicity, extensibility, and verbosity of the implementation.

Comment: I meant the lookup will have to be done during runtime right?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya yes the lookup will happen at runtime

Comment: "Since the error codes cannot conveniently be used as indeces" perhaps, yet a compile time hash function might do the trick.  Post complete error code set.

Comment: @vasia - You can have Hashtable in which you can have key-value pair - You just need to return the value belonging to input key which will be in this case your error code.

Comment: How much is a bunch? If it's more than a boatload, it would probably be worth implementing a hash table. If it's only a gob, then a switch statement is probably your best option.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield only 11, so only a gob. I decided to use an array of const chars, and an enum to index into that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to create an error message structure that contains an `int` field for the error code, and a `char *` field for the error message. Then an array of error message `struct`s can be initialized with error codes and messages. This approach makes it easy to update the code with new error messages, and if the final `struct` in the array of error messages is used as a sentinel with a null pointer in the `.msg` field, functions which iterate over the array will not need to know how many elements it contains.

Here is an example. The `get_error()` function loops over the array, breaking out of the loop when the desired error code is encountered. If the sentinel value is reached and no match has been found, an "Unrecognized error code" message is returned. Note that there is no need to modify the `get_error()` function as new error messages are added to the `error_codes[]` array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Errors
{
    const char *msg;
    int code;
};

struct Errors error_codes[] = {
    { .code = 1,  .msg = "input error" },
    { .code = 5,  .msg = "format error" },
    { .code = 10, .msg = "allocation error" },
    { .msg = NULL }
};

const char * get_error(int err_code);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Error: %s\n", get_error(1));
    printf("Error: %s\n", get_error(5));
    printf("Error: %s\n", get_error(10));
    printf("Error: %s\n", get_error(-1));

    return 0;
}

const char * get_error(int err_code)
{
    struct Errors *current = error_codes;
    const char *ret_msg = "Unrecognized error code";

    while (current->msg) {
        if (current->code == err_code) {
                ret_msg = current->msg;
                break;
        }
        ++current;
    }

    return ret_msg;
}
```

OP has specified `int` error codes, but also mentioned `enum`s. Here is a modification using an `enum`. One advantage of using an `enum` here is increased readablility. A disadvantage is that now code must be modified in two places when error messages change.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Modify both the Error_Codes enum  and the following error_codes[] array
   when adding new error messages. */

enum Error_Codes {
    ERRINPUT  = 1,
    ERRFORMAT = 5,
    ERRALLOC  = 10
};

struct Errors
{
    const char *msg;
    enum Error_Codes code;
};

struct Errors error_codes[] = {
    { .code = ERRINPUT,  .msg = "input error" },
    { .code = ERRFORMAT, .msg = "format error" },
    { .code = ERRALLOC,  .msg = "allocation error" },
    { .msg = NULL }
};

const char * get_error(enum Error_Codes err_code);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Error: %s\n", get_error(ERRINPUT));
    printf("Error: %s\n", get_error(ERRFORMAT));
    printf("Error: %s\n", get_error(ERRALLOC));
    printf("Error: %s\n", get_error(-1));

    return 0;
}

const char * get_error(enum Error_Codes err_code)
{
    struct Errors *current = error_codes;
    const char *ret_msg = "Unrecognized error code";

    while (current->msg) {
        if (current->code == err_code) {
                ret_msg = current->msg;
                break;
        }
        ++current;
    }

    return ret_msg;
}
```

Program output:

```
Error: input error
Error: format error
Error: allocation error
Error: Unrecognized error code
```

Comment: this isn't the approach that I ended up taking, but it is elegant enough, and if I had more than 11 error codes this would be the way to go. I settled for an array of const *chars, and an enum that I use to index into it. I like your approach, but the only reason I'm not fully sold on it is that you have to iterate through the array of structs and compare error codes.

Comment: Of course there are many ways to skin a cat. The thing that I like about this approach is that changing or adding error messages is easy. You only need to modify the code in one place. For error messages, I don't think that efficiency is a primary concern; ease of maintenance on the other hand does seem fundamentally important.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I am considering switching to your approach. If nobody posts a solution that uses generative macros/enums that is also better than yours (imo) I will mark this as accepted, shortly.

Comment: @vasia -- I added a version using an `enum`. This trades modification in one place only for improved readability. There might be a way to use x macros here to avoid the need to change code in two places, but I'm not sure that it would be worth it; a comment in the code may be as effective ;)

Comment: Interesting: use of `enum Error_Codes` in `get_error(), even though `enum Error_Codes { ...} code;` defined within `struct Errors`.  In a typical application, I'd expect `enum Error_Codes` defined inside a .h file and `struct Errors` within a .c file.

Comment: @chux -- I probably should have moved the `enum` definition out of the `struct` from the start; have done so now.